# Android triggers jQuerys 'beforeunload' when screen turns off

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome

I have the same website for mobile and desktop devices. One weird behavior I discovered is on mobile devices - Android and Chrome browser.
I didnt have the opportunity to discover exact trigger of the behavior but I think it has something to do with screen turning off.

I have this code before unload. On desktop it works fine.

```
$(document).on('beforeunload',function(){
    $('.loading').show();
})
```

On phone it works also good but when I minimize Chrome or screen turns off and I wake up the phone. It triggers beforeunload event. Because of that I need to reload the page. I tried also small workaround that clicking on the .loading class will hide it, but with this behavior it doesnt work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: this is a browser event, not a jQuery event. and why event display `.loading` when about to unload?

Comment: sorry for not 100% correct expressions, because its bound with load eventListener so basically I show loading before unload and before loading full page

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: unfortunately no, I set 20 seconds but i think solution can be here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704934/6504337