# 'beforeunload' event triggers when page is left in the background on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a simple loading spinner that pops up when navigating. It shows up using a 'beforeunload' event when navigating away and uses the 'load' event to hide itself again when it is done.

The problem is that when I leave the page in the background on my phone for e.g. a few hours the 'beforeunload' event triggers and displays the spinner. Probably because Chrome on Android is partially unloading the page to save memory. The spinner doesn't go away by itself though and I can't seem to figure out how to make it disappear again in an elegant way.

Is there any other event I should be using instead?

```js
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        topSpinner.classList.add("closed");
    });

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
        topSpinner.classList.remove("closed");
    });
```

Comment: same issue here :-(

Comment: I've created a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/ov6b9pdL/ Open this on your mobile Chrome (Android?) browser. Switch off screen for 5-10 minutes and go back to browser. In my case I can see the loading layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome 68 (July 2018) introduced a new [Page Lifecycle API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api): the state diagram supplied in this link does not show the System (browser) calling `beforeunload` before putting the page into the `frozen` state, but that is clearly what is happening.

Helpfully, the API introduced two new events that trigger as the page enters and exits this state: `freeze` and `resume`.

I've solved this problem on both mobile chrome and webview displays simply by adding this:

```
document.addEventListener('resume', (event) => {
  // The page has been unfrozen: remove the spinner if it's active
 topSpinner.classList.add("closed");
});
```

Comment: I see the solution but any idea about the possible cause? Also, looks like from the Page Lifecycle API that it is possible after 'beforeUnload' it goes to freeze and then is revived. But I guess this would be hard to trace/debug.

Answer (score 0):

Change the load event listerner to focus

Answer (score 0):

I've logged events via Ajax to database. My tests showed, that it's not predictable which events were triggered (i.e. when using PWA). There are `focus`, `visibilitychange`, `resize` and `beforeunload` involved. I was surprised about when switching screen on with active PWA, sometimes `beforeunload` is the only events that has been logged to database.

I'm using the following code now, that I've found at [Kleiderliebe](https://www.kleiderliebe.de/), which seems to work without sideeffects:

```
var visibilityState = 'visible';
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if (visibilityState === 'visible') {
        loader.show(e);
    }
});
window.addEventListener('focus', loader.hide);
window.addEventListener('resize', loader.hide);
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
    visibilityState = document.visibilityState;
    if (visibilityState === 'visible') {
        loader.hide(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to persist a loader flag via `localStorage`, so if the page then reloaded, check the flag again:

Pseudo code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#loader').hide();
  localStorage.setItem("loader", false);

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', showLoader);
});

var showLoader = function() {
  var isShow = localStorage.getItem("loader");
  if(!isShow){
      $('#loader').show();
      localStorage.setItem("loader", true);
  }
};
```

Comment: This would not help for use-case of OP, because when switching on mobile screen from standby the page is not really reloaded.

Comment: So maybe by using setTimeout function every x second to check the state could be helpful in such case?

Comment: Not very user-friendly. Imagine a situation where you switch on your mobile screen with opened browser. The first thing you will see is the loader icon which will be removed due to `setTimeout` after `x` seconds, so in worst case you have to wait `x` seconds to see page again. Additionally using a timer that is running all the time for this special case is not really innovative.

Comment: No, I mean timer to check the flag value above.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please edit your code to show how this should work.